# jQuery .appendTo() on a <ul> working on all <ul> not on the specified <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I am trying to create a list which changes it's first element on click of up/down. [This is what i want to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/9NJ2Z/)

This code is working excellent. but problem is i'm using list in main menu of my site also, and this code adds the same list item in my main menu also (on first/last position).

i changed the script something like this to make change in only specified list not in all lists i have used in my page, but no effect.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        $('#scrollup, #scrolldown').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();   
            var id = e.target.id;
        if(id == 'scrollup'){
            $('div #news ul li:first').appendTo('ul');
        }else{
            $('div #news ul li:last').prependTo('ul');
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Please help to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of only `ul` use `appendTo('div #id ul')`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('#scrollup').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div #news ul li:first').appendTo('div #news ul');
    });
    $('#scrolldown').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div #news ul li:last').prependTo('div #news 'ul');
    });
});
```